# Finding limit if it exist

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I Have to find the following limits, if they exist

$$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} Ne^{-k_1t}$$
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} - \frac{k_1N}{k_2-k_1} \ e^{-k_2t} + \frac{k_1N}{k_2-k_1} \ e^{-k_1t}$$
$$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{k_1N}{k_2-k_1} \ e^{-k_2t}-\frac{k_2N}{k_2-k_1} \ e^{-k_1t}-\displaystyle \frac{k_1N}{k_2-k_1}+\frac{k_2N}{k_2-k_1}$$

Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Are $N$ and $k_1$ constants? If they are, do you know if they are positive, zeo or negative?

Comment: They are konstants. $N$ is positive and $k_1 \ne k_2$ but $k_1,k_2 > 0$

Comment: Just use $e^{-at} \to 0$ for any $a>0.$

Comment: For the first one you have
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to \infty}Ne^{-k_1t}&=\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{N}{e^{k_1t}}\\&=0\qquad\text{since }e^{k_1t}\to \infty
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the fact that
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}-k_nt=-\infty,\qquad\text{for }n=1,2$$
$$\lim_{t\to-\infty}e^t=0$$

The first one: $$\lim_{t\to\infty}Ne^{-k_1t} = 0$$

The second one:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \left(
\frac{k_1N}{k_2-k_1}e^{-k_1t}-\frac{k_1N}{k_2-k_1}e^{-k_2t}
\right)=
\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{k_1N}{k_2-k_1}\left(
e^{-k_1t}-e^{-k_2t}
\right)=0$$

The third one:

$$\lim_{t \to \infty}\left( \frac{k_1N}{k_2-k_1} \ e^{-k_2t}-\frac{k_2N}{k_2-k_1} \ e^{-k_1t}-\frac{k_1N}{k_2-k_1}+\frac{k_2N}{k_2-k_1}\right)=\frac{(k_2-k_1)N}{k_2-k_1}=N$$